# Exception "A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed" thrown when using event handler

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, event-handling, console-application

I have an event handler in my C# console app project that is triggered when an update from the user has arrived (a chatbot scenario). The problem is that even though I use await inside the event handler, I still get an exception(Invalid operation exception) when code reaches the point where it wants to fetch user data from the database.

On the other hand, when I let go of the event handler and use a long polling technique the get the updates, I do not encounter this issue. I'm thinking maybe this event handler creates a new thread for each update it receives, so that's why this exception is thrown. I Was wondering if I could use event handlers and not face this issue? Here is my code:

```
 public class TelegramService : IChatbotService
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly ITelegramBotClientFactory _telegramBotFactory;
        private ITelegramBotClient _telegramBotClient;
        internal static User Me;
        private readonly IChatbotUpdateHandler _chatbotUpdateHandler;
        private readonly ISettingService _settingService;

        public TelegramService(ITelegramBotClientFactory telegramBotClientFactory, ILogger<TelegramService> logger,
            IChatbotUpdateHandler chatbotUpdateHandler)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _telegramBotFactory = telegramBotClientFactory;
            _chatbotUpdateHandler = chatbotUpdateHandler;

        }
        public async Task<bool> Run()
        {

            try
            {
                _telegramBotClient = _telegramBotFactory.CreateBotClient();

                await _telegramBotClient.DeleteWebhookAsync();


                Me = await _telegramBotClient.GetMeAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"502 bad gateway, restarting in 2 seconds:\n\n{e.Message}", e.Message);
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
                //API is down... 
                return true;
            }
          
            _telegramBotClient.OnUpdate += BotOnUpdateReceived; // event handler

            _telegramBotClient.StartReceiving();

            return false;
        }

  private async void BotOnUpdateReceived(object sender, UpdateEventArgs args)
        {
            var update = args.Update;
            if (update.Type == UpdateType.InlineQuery) return;
            if (update.Type == UpdateType.CallbackQuery) return;

            await _chatbotUpdateHandler.Handle(update);

        }

}

public class TelegramUpdateHandler : IChatbotUpdateHandler
    {

        private Update _update;
        private readonly ILogger<TelegramUpdateHandler> _logger;
        private readonly IUserService _userService;
        private readonly IChatProcessorFactory _chatProcessorFactory;
        private readonly IUserMessagingService _userMessagingService;

        public TelegramUpdateHandler(ILogger<TelegramUpdateHandler> logger, IUserService userService,
            IChatProcessorFactory chatProcessorFactory, IUserMessagingService userMessagingService)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _userService = userService;
            _chatProcessorFactory = chatProcessorFactory;
            _userMessagingService = userMessagingService;
        }
        public async Task Handle(object updateObject)
        {
            
            try
            {
                var botUser = await GetUser();
               
                await ProcessUpdate(botUser);


            }
            catch (UnAuthorizedException e)
            {
                //User is grounded or does not have access to bot
                _logger.LogInformation($"User is unauthorized to access the bot:\n{e.Message}");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Error occured at Handle:\n{e.Message}");
            }

        }

        private async Task<BotUser> GetUser()
        {
            BotUser botUser = null;

            try
            {
                botUser = await _userService.FetchUser(_update.Message.From.Id);
                //Exception is thrown when calling "FetchUser" when second update comes here.
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException e)
            {
                botUser = _userService.CreateNewBotUser(_update.Message.From);

                botUser = await _userService.AddUserToDb(botUser);
            }

            return botUser;
        }
    }
    

    [Export(typeof(IUserService))]
    public class UserService : IUserService
    {
        private readonly ILanguageService _languageService;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        private readonly ITelegramApiService _telegramApiService;

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public UserService(ITelegramApiService telegramApiService, ILanguageService languageService, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _telegramApiService = telegramApiService;
            _languageService = languageService;
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        public async Task<BotUser> FetchUser(int userId)
        {

            return await _unitOfWork.Users.Fetch(userId);

        }
     }
```

If I change the above to something like below, I don't face any issues:

```
var updates = await GetUpdates(); 
//Through long polling we get the updates rather than using an event handler.

            if (updates.Length > 0)
              {
                  HandleUpdates(updates.ToList());   

                  lastUpdateID = updates[^1].Id;
              }

///........

private async Task HandleUpdates(List<Update> updates)
        {
            foreach (var item in updates)
            {
                if (item.Type == UpdateType.InlineQuery) continue;
                if (item.Type == UpdateType.CallbackQuery) continue;

                await _chatbotUpdateHandler.Handle(item);

            }
        }

/// The rest is similar to the previous version
```

PS*: I also have registered all my services as Transient

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills I added more code to clarify the exact path where the exception is thrown.

Comment: Not enough code. When I can copy and paste it and run it, it is a [mcve]. If I can't, it isn't (yet) a [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills Edited again. Hope this suffices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> event handler in my C# console app project

[`async void` was designed for event handlers, but in a way that assumes they're like UI event handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming):

1. `await` captures the current context and resumes on that context.
2. Exceptions raised from `async void` methods are re-raised on the `SynchronizationContext` that was present at the beginning of the method.
3. There is no way to `await` an `async void` method; the UI just returns to its message loop.

In the UI world, both of these behaviors make sense, and result in the `async void` event handler having similar semantics to a non-`async` event handler. In a Console world, these
behaviors result in these semantics (respectively):

1. After each `await`, the handler will resume executing on a thread pool thread.
2. Exceptions raised from `async void` methods are re-raised directly on the thread pool, which will crash the process.
3. There is no way to `await` an `async void` method, so your code cannot (easily) know when it is complete.

So, `async` event handling in Console processes doesn't work quite as well as within a UI framework. That said, you *can* still use them if you want to; you just have to be aware of these semantics.

Specifically, since an `await` will resume on a thread pool thread, in order to avoid the "second operation" exception, you will need to either:

1. Provide a separate DbContext instance to each event handler.
2. [Change the event handler to support (asynchronous) notifications that the event handlers are complete](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/02/async-oop-5-events.html) (e.g., using Deferrals).
3. Refactor the code so that the events are placed into a queue (e.g., `Channel<T>`) which is processed by a `BackgroundService` component.

Example using the first approach (creating a new DbContext for each handler):

```
private async void BotOnUpdateReceived(object sender, UpdateEventArgs args)
{
  var update = args.Update;
  if (update.Type == UpdateType.InlineQuery) return;
  if (update.Type == UpdateType.CallbackQuery) return;

  var chatbotUpdateHandler = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IChatbotUpdateHandler>();
  await chatbotUpdateHandler.Handle(update);
}
```

Comment: Enjoyed reading your answer. I went on with your first approach, and it's working fine. I thought since I'd already defined the "IChatboUpdateHandler" as a transient service, I'd get a separate object each time the event handler was called. Which was wrong because "TelegramService" is run at the beginning of the app and it's only created once during the application lifetime, therefore, "IChatbotHandler" was also being created once only. The trick was getting new "IChatbotHandler" every time an event is raised, as you perfectly mentioned!